# How to get new mail nofications from Thunderbird 68 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, email, thunderbird

I am an old Thunderbird user sticking with it for over 10 years, and I cannot see any new mail notifications on my old Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) since my last Thunderbird update, which is quite troublesome for my daily work.

I tried searching addons but found no Thunderbird 68 compatible addons exist. I finally updated my Ubuntu to latest LTS 20.04 to see if it is resolved in latest release, but the result is still negative. So, does anyone know a solution to this problem: how can I receive new mail notifications from Thunderbird 68 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @N0rbert The only one that seems working for the current version in the answers is the "birdtray". I tried that, and found that it seems it could detect new incoming mails of thunderbird (I saw that in its log), but it didn't give me any notifications as it should.

Comment: On my Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS the BirdTray 1.6.1 works normally with Thunderbird 68.10. If you have correctly set folders for *Monitoring*, then it should work. I did not checked this on GNOME Shell yet.

Comment: I carefully read BirdTray documentation, and found the default settings for my birdtray is blink off. I dragged the blink slider towards right, and it can now blink when new mail comes. Thanks very much. @N0rbert